# flow function declaration syntax

Tags: flowtype

I am trying to document a factory function in my declaration file.
My goal is to make flow aware of my simple factory.

It's used in koa v2 routes and it's a way to inject some options in my service.

Here is the factory:

```
ctx.compose = function Compose<T: *>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object): T {
  return new service(_.extend({}, ctx._requestOptions, options));
};
```

Because I use koa v2 I created a type KoaCtx in a declaration that look like this:

```
declare type KoaCtx = {
  params: { [key: string]: string },
  request: {
    query: { [key: string]: string },
    body: { [key: string]: string | boolean | Array<any> | Number | Date     | Object },
  },
  body: any,
  req: any,
  res: any,
  state: any,
  ...
  compose: compose: function <T: *>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object): T
}
```

I tried different syntaxes but I keep getting errors.

```
compose: function <T: *>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object): T
                       ^ Unexpected token :
```

If I put the first snippet of code inside my koa route it's working fine!
I tried to add the file with the ctx.compose definition in [include] tag in flow config but it's not working.

**Update**

Tried with this declaration:

```
declare function Compose<T: *>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object): T;

declare type KoaCtx = {
    ...
    compose: Compose<Class<*>>
};
```

But unfortunately it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

A function type looks like

```
(argName1: Type1, argName2: Type2, ...restName: Array<RestType>) => ReturnType
```

a function type with generics looks like

```
<T>(argName1: Type1, argName2: Type2, ...restName: Array<RestType>) => ReturnType
```

So you probably should write

```
declare type KoaCtx = {
  ...
  compose: <T: *>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object) => T
}
```

That said, you're using the existential type `*` as an upper bound for `T`. I'm not sure if that makes much sense here. So I'd just recommend writing

```
declare type KoaCtx = {
  ...
  compose: <T>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object) => T
}
```

As for your update, you can only explicitly instantiate type parameters for type aliases, interfaces, and classes. So you could write

```
declare type Compose = <T>(service: Class<T>, options: ?Object) => T;

declare type KoaCtx = {
    ...
    compose: Compose<MyClass>
};
```

but you can't do that if `Compose` is a generic function.